# clickhouse `DB::Exception: inflateReset failed: buffer error: ZLIB_INFLATE_FAILED` exception

Tags: clickhouse

I've successfully uploaded `csv.gz` files using the following command:

```bash
clickhouse-client --port 19000 \
    --input_format_csv_skip_first_lines 1 \
    --date_time_input_format 'best_effort' \
    -q "INSERT INTO Trade FROM INFILE 'data/mydata.csv.gz' COMPRESSION 'gzip' FORMAT CSV"
```

but for certain files I get the following error:

```bash
DB::Exception: inflateReset failed: buffer error: While executing ParallelParsingBlockInputFormat: While executing File: data for INSERT was parsed from file: (in query: INSERT INTO Marketdepth FROM INFILE
            'data/data.csv.gz' COMPRESSION 'gzip' FORMAT CSV). (ZLIB_INFLATE_FAILED)
```

Is this due to the size of the file? Is there any way I can upload those files?

EDIT:
Tried running without `COMPRESSION 'gzip'` and `FORMAT CSV` but still got the exact same error message.

Comment: Did you try it without the `COMPRESSION 'gip'` clause?

Comment: (For that matter, you don't need the `FORMAT CSV` either)

Comment: still get the same error without `COMPRESSION 'gzip'` and `FORAMT csv`

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is an ongoing issue tracking this error: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/46639

Probably try decompress locally, and insert CSV directly to bypass this edge case for now until the open issue is taken care of?